# how to use QRegExp to grep the last line of output of process?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

am using QRegExp to grep the last line of the QProcess output via

```
QString str (process->readAllStandardOutput());
```

now i want read the last line of str and show that in Statusbar 
please how can get the last line only :(

Comment: Why regexs at all? `str.mid(str.lastIndexOf('\n')+1)` or so.

Comment: got it working using rx.indexIn(line);

Comment: actually i need to get some specific informations from the string thats why i choose QRegExp to  do that ;)

Answer (score 0):

got a working solution using QRegExp

[image: got last line in statusbar :)]

Code sample

```
QString line(download->readAllStandardOutput());
QString progress;
QString timeRemaining;
if (line.contains(QString("[download]"), Qt::CaseInsensitive)) {
    QRegExp rx("(\\d+\\.\\d+%)");
    timeRemaining = line.right(5);
    rx.indexIn(line);
    if(!rx.cap(0).isEmpty()) {
        progress = rx.cap(0);
        progress.chop(3);
        ui->downloadProgressBar->setValue(progress.toInt());
        ui->downloadProgressBar->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        ui->downloadProgressBar->setFormat(timeRemaining);
        ui->statusBar->showMessage(line);
```